# Did I make a &quot;forced&quot; interpretation?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Just a few years ago I wrote an article called [The Geometry of the MRB constant](http://math-blog.com/2010/11/21/the-geometry-of-the-mrb-constant/). Since then I've wondered if there is a better, more natural geometric analysis of the following summation.
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k(k^{1/k}-1)
$$

Here is a rough description of what I did:
[image: part1]

[image: part2]

[image: part3]

Comment: Better than what? Do you expect us to read the whole paper to find that out? Please provide a sketch of the basic idea you used, and point out the relevant parts.

Comment: @MvG I added some excerpts.

Comment: Since you (MRB) invented this constant in the first place, surely any "interpretation" you attach to it is equally valid?

Comment: @mjqxxxx I'm hoping to find someone who can take for a fresh look at its geometry.